# How can I use ListLogLinearPlot to plot wildly different functions?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have two sets of points I need to `ListLogLinearPlot` plot:

```
{{1,10},{10,-20},{100,55},{1000,5000}}
{{1,0.8},{10,2},{100,-0.58},{1000,15}}
```

How can I plot them together with `ListLogLinearPlot`? The second will be an almost flat line around 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick hack borrowed from the how-to on [two-axis plotting](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html):

```
list1 = {{1, 10}, {10, -20}, {100, 55}, {1000, 5000}};
list2 = {{1, 0.8}, {10, 2}, {100, -0.58}, {1000, 15}};

Module[{f = Interpolation[list1, InterpolationOrder -> 1], 
  g = Interpolation[list2, InterpolationOrder -> 1]},
 LogLinearPlot[f[x], {x, Min@list1, Max@list1}];
 LogLinearPlot[f[x], {x, Min@list2, Max@list2}];
 TwoAxisPlot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, Max@list2}]]

TwoAxisPlot[{f_, g_}, {x_, x1_, x2_}] := 
 Module[{fgraph, ggraph, frange, grange, fticks, 
   gticks}, {fgraph, ggraph} = 
   MapIndexed[
    Plot[#, {x, x1, x2}, Axes -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][#2[[1]]]] &, {f, g}]; {frange, 
    grange} = (PlotRange /. 
        AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])[[2]] & /@ {fgraph, ggraph}; 
  fticks = N@FindDivisions[frange, 5];
  gticks = 
   Quiet@Transpose@{fticks, 
      ToString[NumberForm[#, 2], StandardForm] & /@ 
       Rescale[fticks, frange, grange]};
  Show[fgraph, 
   ggraph /. 
    Graphics[graph_, s___] :> 
     Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[graph, 
       RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, grange}, {{0, 1}, frange}]], s], 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{fticks, gticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]]
```

A more straightforward approach might be to normalize and scale the data to a common range and add custom FrameTicks to the left and right sides. Check out [Standardize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Standardize.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Combining all steps in a function that works like `ListLogLinearPlot`:

```
ClearAll[listLogLinearPlot]

listLogLinearPlot = Module[{r1 = MinMax[#[[1, All, 2]]], r2 = MinMax[#[[2, All, 2]]]},
  ListLogLinearPlot[{#[[1]], Transpose[{#, Rescale[#2, r2, r1]} & @@ Transpose[#[[2]]]]},
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[r1, r2]}, 
      {Automatic, Automatic}}, ##2]] &;
```

***Example:***

```
listLogLinearPlot[{l1, l2}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.015], Thick}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"l1", "l2"}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
l1 = {{1, 10}, {10, -20}, {100, 55}, {1000, 5000}};
l2 = {{1, 0.8}, {10, 2}, {100, -0.58}, {1000, 15}};
```

Find the vertical ranges of `l1` and `l2`:

```
{vrange1, vrange2} = MinMax[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ {l1, l2};
```

Rescale the second column of `l2` to the vertical range of `l1`:

```
l2b = Transpose[{#, Rescale[#2, vrange2, vrange1]} & @@ Transpose[l2]];
```

Use `ListLogLinearPlot` with `{l1, l2b}` as input and the function `` Charting`FindTicks[vrange1, vrange2] `` to get the ticks for the right frame:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{l1, l2b}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[.02], Red], Blue}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[vrange1, vrange2]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"l1", "l2"}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]